# Empty Button in admin config

Tags: magento2, admin, frontend-error

[image]

Good morning I have a problem with my store.

activating the Italian translation I report this problem: in the "Checkout" button the text has disappeared. How can I do?
Thanks.

Comment: Please check translation csv

Comment: I checked . But there isn't error.